# What is the difference between "extend self" in a module, and module_function :name_of_method?

Tags: ruby

What is the difference between "extend self" in a module, and module_function :name_of_method?

Example:

```
module Foo
  def bar
    puts 'hi from bar'
  end
  def buu
    puts 'hi from buu'
  end
  extend self
end
```

versus

```
module Foo
  def bar
    puts 'hi from bar'
  end; module_function :bar
  def buu
    puts 'hi from buu'
  end; module_function :buu
end
```

At which point would module_function become equivalent to extend self?

Right now I seem to be using mostly "extend self" and barely ever
module_function.

Answer (score 1):

`extend self` adds all the methods as static methods - but they also remain module methods. That means that when you extend the module from a class, that class will get these methods.

`module_function`, in addition to making the method a module method, also makes the original method private. That means that you won't be able to externally use these methods from objects that extend the module.

You can see the difference in this example:

```
module Foo
  def bar
    puts 'hi from bar'
  end
  def buu
    puts 'hi from buu'
  end
  extend self
end

module Bar
  def bar
    puts 'hi from bar'
  end; module_function :bar
  def buu
    puts 'hi from buu'
  end; module_function :buu
end

class A
  extend Foo
end

class B
  extend Bar
end

Foo::bar
A::bar
Bar::bar
B::bar #Error: private method `bar' called for B:Class (NoMethodError)
```